# Indication when an Azure function is destroyed

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Do i have a way to programmatically identify when a running Azure function is killed/destroyed?

I have a metric value for counting when functions are created - i'm doing it by a global variable `FirstRun` that sets to false in the first run...
Now i need the opposite metric - when is this instance is killed.

Comment: How are you going to use it? (obviously, it can't be in memory since instance is destoyed)

Comment: Write metirc for an external service...

Comment: Can you use the appinsight logs generated by the Function?

Comment: Maybe, but i prefer something more straightforward and less overkill, any other suggestions?